# Senior aged travelers

Tags: trains, luggage, norway, oslo

My wife and I are 75 years old and modestly fit. We fly into Oslo and plan to board the rail to the city center station. We understand the scenic train to Burgin leaves from this station.

My concern is baggage handling. We each will have a 45 pound (~20 kg) bag and a carry on bag. What is the approximate distance to move the bags for each transfer and what about overhead lifting?

Your response will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't find any Burgin in Norway. Do you mean Bergen? The [railway going there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergen_Line) is supposedly scenic.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've been to Oslo, but I believe you can take your luggage on a cart to the train platform under the airport.  I don't know about transferring the luggage to another train at Oslo central station, so I'll leave it to someone who does to post a proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

At the airport, you can get a luggage trolley before getting your bags from the luggage claim area. There is only a very short walk through the terminal, before you can take the lift with the trolley down to the train platform.

Depending on which train you take from the airport to the main railway station, there are luggage racks with more or less space immediately at the entrance to the train carriages, but I would not rely on finding room there. You may have to lift, or get help to lift, your bags onto overhead racks throughout the car.

At the main station, the tracks are at a level below the main station hall. The train from the airport will usually not arrive at the same platform, from which the trains to Bergen departs. There are no trolleys or lifts/elevators at the central station and you must expect to carry your luggage. There are inclined conveyor belts between the platforms and the main station hall.

At the train to Bergen, there are some luggage racks at the entraces, but you must expect limited room. Just as on the train from the airport, you may have to lift or get help to lift your bags onto the overhead racks along the train car.